# Advanced UI In Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

I want to learn advanced customized UI design in Cocoa including UI element design, Is there any book or other good learning source for it?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matt Gemmell did a good talk for NSConference 09 (available on Vimeo for free) called [Designing and Developing Custom Cocoa Controls](http://vimeo.com/17158932). He also had a recent blog post about [API design](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/) where he discusses the thought process of designing a GUI component.

Answer (score 3):

As a good starting point I'd check out [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com) they have a lot if advanced custom UI projects, and a lot of them are open source, Apache, and MIT liscenced.